# Como fazer deploy de API ASP .NET com front-end

Tags: .net, asp.net, hospedagem

Olá, estou buscando conhecimentos para publicar meu primeiro site em ASP .NET Core, mas por inexperiência não sei como funciona, pois é bem diferente de todos que já publiquei. **Queria saber como faz para fazer o deploy tanto da API quanto do front-end juntos**, pois eu upei a API na SmarterAsp.net mas ainda falta o front end e estou sofrendo para descobrir como faria para fazer essa publicação dos dois juntos e fazer eles se comunicarem.

[Imagem da API funcionando normalmente na hospedagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95wXM.png)

Parei para pensar e acredito que tenha que hospedar a API em um domínio e o front-end em outro domínio e conectá-los, mas não tenho certeza disso.

Comment: Bom dia Gabriel! É possível publicar ambos no mesmo domínio, contudo, diria para separar em 2 domínios diferentes igual você mesmo colocou na sua pergunta. Também indicaria você a utilizar o Microsoft Azure, é intuitivo e você consegue dar deploy das suas aplicações facilmente. Para novas contas, você ganha alguns serviços de graça por 12 meses e + $200 em crédito: https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/free/

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: bom dia @gregoryp, no caso eu teria que contratar dois domínios diferentes e pagar pelos dois e assim certamente funcionaria, certo? Há alguma maneira de não deixar a API visível caso alguém consiga descobrir a URL na qual a API está hospedada?

Comment: Por isso indiquei o Azure. Por lá, tanto para API quanto para um Web App (site), eles te dão o domínio de "graça", o que é cobrado é apenas o plano. E há planos gratuitos. Um domínio para o seu site ficaria assim, por exemplo: alunosapi.azurewebsites.net. Caso ninguém tenha escolhido, você pode utilizar. É claro que se você quiser, você pode conectar um domínio próprio para este domínio do azure. Contudo, nos meus projetos, eu só fáco isso para o Web App,  uma vez que é algo visível ao público. Para a API eu deixo o endereço padrão do Azure e tenho 1 custo a menos.

Comment: Referente a API ficar escondida, se o usuário tem um pouco mais de conhecimento, ele consegue, através do seu site principal, descobrir qual API está sendo chamada. Contudo, há formas de não deixar qualquer pessoa acessar/utilizar sua API, como por exemplo tokens de autenticação para chamar/consumir os métodos, além de um usuário/senha caso a pessoa descubra o endereço da API.

Comment: Eu testei utilizar o Azure, mas achei bem complicado no meu primeiro contato, por isso quis mudar para usar outra plataforma de hospedagem, mas você falou coisas interessantes que pode fazer eu voltar atrás. Mas teria primeiro de aprender a usar a plataforma antes de tudo.

Comment: Referente a autenticação, eu utilizo tokens JWT para a maioria dos métodos da API, então isso não seria um problema.